# Decomposition of $z= x+y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a $ n\times n$ symmetric matrix with $A^2=I$ and $A\neq \pm I$

Prove that every vector $z$ has a decomposition $z=x+y$ such that $Ax=x$ and $Ay=-y$

Considering A to be a $2 \times 2$ matrix and $z\in\mathbb{R}^2$ Since $A^2=I$, the eigenvalues are $-1,+1$.
Also the eigenvectors of repective eigenvalues are linearly independent . So dimension of $\mathbb{R}^2 $= dimension of eigenspace of $+1$, $-1$ $=2$.
But I am lost when $A$ is a $3×3 $ or other  $n\times n$ matrix

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is symmetric, $\mathbb{R}^n$ has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors of $A$. Since $A^2=\operatorname{Id}$, the eigenvalues are all $1$ or $-1$. So, let $E_1$ be the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $1$ and let $E_{-1}$ be the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $-1$. Then $\mathbb{R}^n=E_1\oplus E_{-1}$. Every $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written in one and only one way as $v_1+v_{-1}$, with $Av_1=v_1$ and $Av_{-1}=-v_{-1}$.